# In EC2, how do I do a traditional redirect?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, domain, redirect, url

When users hit mydomain.com, I want them to redirect to another page.

I know I can do this through:

- my name registrar
- my DNS servers

But I would like to do it through EC2. How can I set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is vague, because the question is vague. :)

1. Setup a web server on the EC2 box.
2. Configure the web server to redirect any hits to it to wherever you want them to go instead.